# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token this Javasctript Error

Tags: javascript, keyboard, syntax-error

Trying to create an actor class for an html5 game, but I get an Uncaught SyntaxError. Not sure at all what it means or how to fix it. Other questions like this are usually about Jquery and I couldn't find any solutions that fit my problem.

```
    function Actor(x, y){
//...
        this.direction = 270;
//...
    }


    Actor.prototype.update = function(){
        if(this.speed >= this.maxspeed)
            this.speed = this.maxspeed;

            if(Key.isDown(Key.getCode("a")) this.direction -= 1; // < -- ERROR OCCURS HERE
            if(Key.isDown(Key.getCode("d")) this.direction +=1;
            if(Key.isDown(Key.getCode(" ") this.move();
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(Key.isDown(Key.getCode("a")) this.direction -= 1;
```

You have 3 opening parens, and only 2 closing ones.

```
if(Key.isDown(Key.getCode("a"))) this.direction -= 1;
//                             ^ added
```

You have multiple lines with this same problem.  Correct them all.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing a closing parentheses in all your if statements. They should be

```
if(Key.isDown(Key.getCode("a"))) this.direction -= 1;
if(Key.isDown(Key.getCode("d"))) this.direction +=1;
if(Key.isDown(Key.getCode(" "))) this.move();
```